# List Output Help

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

How would I create a list then on click add data to the list which is then stored into a session variable, then on another page retrieve the variable and output them? Currently I have:

**Page Load:**

`List <myClass> listName=new List<myClass>`

**OnClick:**

`listName.add(3);
listName.add(4);`

`Session[“IDs”]=listName;`

**Second Page**

????

I need to get the whole list and add output the list so I can output (hopefully) the ‘3’ and ‘4’.

Comment: `3` and `4` and are invalid identifiers for instances of myClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<myClass> listNames = (List<myClass>)Session[“IDs”];
```

You can read about it on MSDN: [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)